# P-Values of a phi factor intercorrelation in r

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, p-value, factor-analysis

I conducted an exploratory factor analysis with an oblimin rotation based on a polychoric correlation matrix because my data didn´t have multivariate normality. I got the factors and the loadings as output and everything is fine with them. I also got a matrix with factor correlations as an output (phi coefficient). Now, to report this matrix, i wanted to put an apa-conform table into my thesis. At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Table]

I do need to report p-values though and i cant seem to find them anywhere in my fa-output. Does anyone have an idea how to conduct the p-values for the phi-correlations?
Thanks in advance!